# Set window size bigger than monitor resolution?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, resolution

What I'm really trying to do is to play a single screen game (emulated) across multiple monitors (at full 1080p on each window). I figure if I can render the game at a bigger resolution I can then copy a quarter of it to each screen.

I can use [OnTopReplica](https://github.com/LorenzCK/OnTopReplica) to do the copying part I believe. It seems to work with a good fps.

I was hoping to either emulate a bigger monitor (couldn't find a solution), or make the window bigger than the monitor. I tried [Sizer 4](http://www.brianapps.net/sizer4/) but when I make it taller than the monitor, it seems to max out to the monitors height (not sure if this is because of windows or sizer).

Anyone have another solution I might try?

Comment: If both are attached to your PC why not just drag the window across both displays?

Comment: I wish to make the window twice as tall as well

Comment: I still don't get what problem you would have if each display has the same resolution? Why would you want to double your physical vertical space? The result would be a window that you either can't move/access the menu or 50% of it would be off screen. A lot of drivers support custom resolutions that might help you out.

Comment: After the screen is made to bigger than the actual window i can use ontopreplica to mirror a part of that big screen to each monitor

Comment: If you have that many monitors, you can arrange them to be 2 over and 2 under, which would allow you to have a larger window size.  Using OnTopReplica, you should be able to just select the portion of the window you want for each monitor and just expand the replica to fill each screen.  No need to make the original game/emulator be larger than a screen.

Comment: That's an interesting idea, i will have to try that. Rearranging monitors before and after may get anything to do  though, so i still hope to find another solution.

Comment: I still don't get what your specific requirements are. If you take a window and drag it across two displays you will have part of it displayed on either display. If you're actively playing there isn't really any reason for another window to steal your focus. As your displays are all the same size you also don't have to worry about a window being smaller on a second screen or bigger. Does the emulator not support this? Do you have some other secondary requirements you have not stated?